# How did this question get deleted? It had an answer

Tags: discussion

I just complained that this question had been deleted

[How to focus the next focusable field in browsers whose keyCode is readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028857/how-to-focus-the-next-focusable-field-in-browsers-whose-keycode-is-readonly)

I was massively downvoted here at META because the asker himself had deleted it so I deleted my META question to not get more downvotes. HOWEVER I suddenly realised that I was correct in not understanding why it was deleted. I had answered it. So how could the user with a 3 digit rep delete his own question when there was an answer?

NOTE: I rewrote the title of the SO question and voted to re-open it and now it is...

Comment: Thanks - I could not find that tiny nugget of info about the non-upvoted answer. And my question got downvoted. Who are the DV addicts here?

Comment: I can't see any answer on that question

Comment: One tip: don't ask not to be downvoted. That seems to only invite them. But then again, don't worry too much about Meta downvotes. They come far more easily than on SO itself. And the rep here doesn't mean much.

Comment: @mplungjan Downvoting [works a bit differently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47635/50049) on Meta. Your question isn't at all bad, its just come up quite a few times before. Things can .. be a little hard to find here, so don't take it personally.

Comment: But I still hate to be downvoted and cannot fathom who does it on such flimsy premises. Thanks for the link. Since THIS question now has an upvoted answer I cannot delete it :|

Comment: Don't worry about that. Dupes don't necessarily do any harm. Might be a decent alternative formulation pointing to the dupe.

Comment: I agree - it will be closed anyway now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there no answer in the post, or if there is only one answer with 0 or less score then OP can delete the question.